# Increased IOPS after making materialized view

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, provisioned-iops

Recently we moved away Secondary indexes to Materialized view in Cassandra.This was because SASI index was collapsing because of our frequent updates, also we were moving into the limitation of maximum five entries per index for SASI sparse index. 
Earlier had one particular materialized view with our table
The base table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chats (
    user_id bigint,
    peer_id bigint,
    msg_id text,
    text text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, peer_id, msg_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (msg_id ASC)
```

and materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS chats_by_updated AS
    SELECT * FROM chats
    WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL AND updated_at IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, updated_at, peer_id, msg_id)
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (updated_at ASC, peer_id ASC, msg_id ASC)
```

We decided to add one other materialized view

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS chats_by_updated AS
    SELECT * FROM chats
    WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL AND updated_at IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, peer_id, updated_at, msg_id)
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (updated_at ASC, peer_id ASC, msg_id ASC)
```

The change worked smoothly for one day After that one of the nodes started acting up randomly. I am talking about 42 load average in a 16 core machine with 3k IOPS. All the other nodes were working fine with ~10 wa stat except this one particular node which was around ~70 wa in top.

Checking AWS EBS dashboard I saw that the EBS queue length is around ~30 and the read and write latencies are around ~15 ms for this node which is huge.
The pattern isis equal parts read and write. The writes are a constant stream of rows having around ~15 columns.

This is confusing because only one select is issued for multiple MVs. The read throughput should not have increased. I am not able to understand if this is happening due to adding one more MV or some other problem.
What am I missing ?

Comment: It's not clear what does your workload do. Does it do writes? Reads? Both? How much of each? Are the writes "interactive" (come in sporadically based on client requests) or "batch" (some sort of client code wants to write a bunch of new data and does it in a loop)?

Comment: @NadavHar'El edited for clarity